# Auto sync data from firebase to google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, firebase-realtime-database, google-sheets

Every time a change is made in my RealtimeDB, I need to get those data to my Google Sheet without pressing any button. How to achieve this?

PS. The following code does exactly what I mentioned but not automatically

```
function getData() {
var firebaseUrl = "https://databse.firebaseio.com/Items";
var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
var data = base.getData();

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

var num = 2;
range = sheet.getRange("A"+num+":D"+num+"");
  
var range2 = sheet.getRange("A2:D");
range2.clearContent();

  
for(var i in data) {
  var values = [
  [ data[i].itemname, data[i].itembarcode, data[i].itemprice]
  ];
  range.setValues(values);
  num += 1;
  range = ss.getRange("A"+num+":D"+num+"");
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To automatically update the sheet when the database changes, you have two options:

1. Periodically refresh the sheet with the database contents. You can accomplish this by running your `getData` function on a trigger.
2. Listen to realtime updates from the database. While Firebase has this option, it isn't available in the `FirebaseApp` library.

If you want to push updates to the sheet as they happen, you'll have to push them into your sheet from an environment that *does* support listening for realtime updates. Doug Stevenson wrote a great example of this on [Copying data from Firebase Realtime Database to a Google Sheet in real time via Cloud Functions](https://gist.github.com/CodingDoug/ffc4f050cc489a0280eb7f4cbe36af07).